# CSS Make Div Text Stay On 1 Line

Tags: css, xenforo

So I'm trying to make a custom login bar for my Xenforo website theme, I've created a custom navigationbar and am trying to add in the Login etc but when I do it I get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3hfy.png

Can anyone help me make it so it's all on 1 line instead of 3 seperate lines? My website is www.royaltymc.net
Here is the actual bar code:

```html
     <div class="navTabs4">
      <xen:if is="@uix_pageStyle==1">
      <div class="pageWidth">
      </xen:if>
       
       <ul class="publicTabs navLeft">
 
       <xen:if is="( @uix_navigationStickyLogo && @uix_stickyNavigation ) || @uix_navStyle == 2">
       <li id="logo_small">
        <a href="{$logoLink}">
        <xen:if is="@uix_smallLogoPath">
         <img src="@uix_smallLogoPath">
        <xen:elseif is="@uix_logoText"/>
         <h2 class="uix_textLogo"><xen:if is="@uix_logoTextIcon"><i class="uix_icon @uix_logoTextIcon"></i></xen:if><xen:if is="@uix_logoText">@uix_logoText</xen:if></h2>
        <xen:else/>
         <img src="@headerLogoPath" alt="{$xenOptions.boardTitle}" />
        </xen:if>
        </a>
       </li>
       </xen:if>
       <!-- Shop -->
       <xen:if is="@uix_loginTriggerPosition == 1">
        <xen:include template="uix_loginTab" />
       </xen:if>
       
        
        <!-- extra tabs: middle -->
        <xen:if is="{$extraTabs.middle}">
        <xen:foreach loop="$extraTabs.middle" key="$extraTabId" value="$extraTab">
         <xen:if is="{$extraTab.linksTemplate}">
          <li class="navTab {$extraTabId} <xen:if is="@uix_removeTabLinks">{xen:if $extraTab.selected, 'selected'} Popup PopupControl PopupClosed<xen:else />{xen:if $extraTab.selected, 'selected', 'Popup PopupControl PopupClosed'}</xen:if>">
         
          <a href="{$extraTab.href}" class="navLink<xen:if is="!@uix_navDropdownArrows"> NoPopupGadget</xen:if>"<xen:if is="!@uix_navDropdownArrows"> rel="Menu"</xen:if>>{$extraTab.title}<xen:if is="{$extraTab.counter}"><strong class="itemCount"><span class="Total">{$extraTab.counter}</span><span class="arrow"></span></strong></xen:if></a>
          <a href="{$extraTab.href}" class="SplitCtrl" rel="Menu"></a>
          
          <div class="<xen:if is="@uix_removeTabLinks">Menu JsOnly tabMenu<xen:else />{xen:if {$extraTab.selected}, 'tabLinks', 'Menu JsOnly tabMenu'}</xen:if> {$extraTabId}TabLinks">
           {xen:if '{$extraTab.selected} && @uix_pageStyle == 1 && !@uix_removeTabLinks', '<div class="pageWidth">'}
            <div class="primaryContent menuHeader">
             <h3>{$extraTab.title}</h3>
             <div class="muted">{xen:phrase quick_links}</div>
            </div>
            {xen:raw $extraTab.linksTemplate}
            <xen:if is="{$extraTab.selected}"><xen:include template="uix_tabLinksSearch" /></xen:if>
           {xen:if '{$extraTab.selected} && @uix_pageStyle == 1 && !@uix_removeTabLinks', '</div>'}
          </div>
         </li>
         <xen:else />
          <li class="navTab {$extraTabId} {xen:if $extraTab.selected, 'selected', 'PopupClosed'}">
           <a href="{$extraTab.href}" class="navLink<xen:if is="!@uix_navDropdownArrows"> NoPopupGadget</xen:if>"<xen:if is="!@uix_navDropdownArrows"> rel="Menu"</xen:if>>{$extraTab.title}<xen:if is="{$extraTab.counter}"><strong class="itemCount"><span class="Total">{$extraTab.counter}</span><span class="arrow"></span></strong></xen:if></a>
           <xen:if is="!@uix_removeTabLinks"><xen:if is="{$extraTab.selected}"><div class="tabLinks"><xen:include template="uix_tabLinksSearch" /></div></xen:if></xen:if>
          </li>
         </xen:if>
        </xen:foreach>
        </xen:if>
        
        
        
 
       </ul>
       
       
       
       <xen:if is="{$uix_searchPosition} == 2">
        <xen:include template="uix_searchMinimal" />
       </xen:if>
         
        
      <xen:if is="@uix_pageStyle==1"></div></xen:if>
     </div>
```

Here is my HTML Login Bar Code: (Lot's of uncessary code, not sure which bits to take out)

```html
<xen:if is="!{$visitor.user_id} && {$contentTemplate} != 'login' && {$contentTemplate} != 'login_with_error'">

 <li class="navTab login{xen:if '@uix_loginTriggerStyle == 2', ' Popup PopupControl'} PopupClosed">
  <xen:if is="@uix_loginTriggerStyle == 1"><label for="LoginControl"></xen:if>
   <a href="{xen:link login}" class="navLink uix_dropdownDesktopMenu{xen:if '@uix_loginTriggerStyle == 2', ' NoPopupGadget'}{xen:if '@uix_loginTriggerStyle == 3', ' OverlayTrigger'}"{xen:if '@uix_loginTriggerStyle == 2',  'rel="Menu"'}>
    <xen:if is="@uix_loginTriggerIcons"><i class="uix_icon uix_icon-signIn"></i> </xen:if>
    <strong><b><font color="white">Login</font></b></strong>
   </a>
  <xen:if is="@uix_loginTriggerStyle == 1"></label></xen:if>
  
  <xen:if is="@uix_loginTriggerStyle == 2">
  <div class="Menu JsOnly tabMenu uix_fixIOSClick">
   <div class="secondaryContent uix_loginForm">
    <xen:include template="uix_loginForm" />
   </div>
  </div>
  </xen:if>
  
 </li>
 
 <a> or </a>
 
 <xen:if is="@uix_loginShowRegister && {$contentTemplate} != 'register_form'">
 <li class="navTab register PopupClosed">
  <a href="{xen:link register}" class="navLink">
   <xen:if is="@uix_loginTriggerIcons"><i class="uix_icon uix_icon-register"></i> </xen:if>
   <strong><font color="white"> Create a new account</font></strong>
  </a>
 </li>
 </xen:if>
 
</xen:if>
```

Here is my code CSS for it:

*NOTE*: If you need any other code, don't hesitate to ask!

```css
 .navTabs4
 {
  @property "navTabs";
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #00254F;
      line-height: 37px;
      text-align: center;
  border-color: @uix_primaryBorder.border-color;
  border-radius: @uix_globalLargeBorderRadius;
  background-clip: content-box;
  @property "/navTabs";
  height: 40px;
 }
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant html to your snippet, please?

Comment: Added the html for you

Comment: Hmm. Okay... well to start with if you're going to have `<li>login</li>` followed by `<a>or</a>`, followed by `<li>Create New Account</li>`, you're probably best off putting the `or` inside a list item as well: `<li><a>or</a></li>`. Though it isn't at all clear why any of this text constitutes a list item or why you have an empty anchor around `<a>or</a>`. It looks like you don't really understand the elements or the roles they play?

Comment: Ah... okay... I'm sorry to say this, but the markup is a complete mess. For example, you wouldn't write: `<li><a href="#"><strong><b><font color="white">Login</font></b></strong></a><li>`... you'd just write: `<li><a href="#">Login</a></li>` and style the text using `color:` and `font-weight:`

Comment: Yeah, I don't really understand the elements or the roles, I just know it  shows text and worked :P. I added the <li> tags but I don't really understand your 2nd comment, could you possibly explain a little more?

Comment: Markup isn't desktop publishing. When you write `html`, you're not moving things around a 2-dimensional canvas, you're describing what role each element plays in the document and (99% of the time) no more than that. So you might tell the browser "This part of the document is a list item." But if it isn't, then... you wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS code to your stylesheets:

```
.navTab { display: inline-block; }
```

If it doesn't work, try adding !important after the inline-block statement.